# Asterisk command "sip show peers" times out

Tags: java, asterisk

My code executes a command in console asterisk and all commands works fine, but `sip show peers` doesn't work.

I've 12 VOIP servers and in 4 servers, `sip show peers` doesn't work, but all other commands (`sip show channels`, `dundi show peers`) works

The exception generated is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.asteriskjava.manager.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response to Command
at org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.sendAction(ManagerConnectionImpl.java:737)
at org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.sendAction(ManagerConnectionImpl.java:701)
at org.asteriskjava.manager.DefaultManagerConnection.sendAction(DefaultManagerConnection.java:283)
at manager.Manager.run(Manager.java:47)
at manager.Manager.main(Manager.java:70)
```

My code

```
OriginateAction originateAction;
originateAction = new OriginateAction();

c.login();
CommandAction action;
CommandResponse response;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
action = new CommandAction();

action.setCommand("sip show peers ");

response = (CommandResponse) c.sendAction(action);
```

The firewall is ok and manager.conf is ok (because others commands work).

Comment: Try remove space after "peers"

Comment: doenst works 

action.setCommand("sip show peers");

Answer (score 0):

have you debugged why the 4 servers do not work with "sip show peers", I would assume it is timing out

In your Java try to put an output right after each connection, to see if it is network related.